# Angular ng-if with ng-init

Tags: angularjs

Why does this code show all 4 names on output?

```
<div data-ng-app="">
  <div data-ng-init="names=['dave','melissa','lisa','jill']">
    <div data-ng-repeat="data in names" ng-if="data == 'dave'">
        {{ data }}
    </div>
 </div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fergnab/gxycncpj/)

Comment: That's odd! I don't know why this is happening, but If this needs to be solved in a timely manner, the above code works with `ng-show`.

Comment: @WalterRoman, ya, it took me awhile, but jsFiddle had the wrong Angular library selected. Thanks

Comment: @Fergus try to avoid `ng-init`, just a tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong angular.js build on jsFiddle.. need Angular 1.1.5 or greater..